# Honeycomb like view with fragment and listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

We are developing an app that in one point, we need a screen like Honeycomb Gmail application :

http://www.cnx-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/android_3.0_honeycomb_gmail_app_fragments_700px.png

We are trying to use fragments and includes a listview to show our items.
We did exactly the same thing on this link : http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial

But in any way we did not able to view different layouts,
what i mean is that, the only thing that we can show on the right fragment a single textview. 
but we need a listview there, that we can view a thumbnail,some explanations and this needs to be clickable.

anyone to help?

Comment: You should look into custom adapters. What you want to do is make a listview with a custom adapter instead of the standard plug and play adapters.

Comment: We have already use custom adapters and ListFragment instead of single  Activity or Fragment but even we used setListAdapter(myAdapter), we cannot see our layout in the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work.  I think you want to instantiate a ListFragment that, upon the user selecting a row, instantiates another ListFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) article aswell.

Below is an example for a layout xml file that has two fragments next to each other with an even width.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <fragment 
        class="package.of.fragmentA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        />
    <fragment
        class="package.of.fragmentB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the case of the GMail application the class **fragmentA** would be a ListFragment and **fragmentB** would be a normal fragment class with a custom layout file.

Comment: we did as you said but, even we used not a listview but a single button, still we are not able to view it.Is there something that we miss, like committing listview or adding it in any other functions?